# How sendAction works...?

Tags: ember.js

`this.sendAction('test');`

Why test property should be defined to call that function.

Why its not working if i directly call like:

`sendAction("test2")?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because sendAction isn't global, it targets the particular component you're working in.